# Probability Inequality Problems for Normal Distributions

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

[image]

As the title mentions that, X~N(0,1) and ε>0.
My former try is find some inequality for exp or mean inequality, but failed.

Comment: I haven't checked myself, but this feels like Markov's inequality or Chebyshev's inequality could be useful.

Comment: @HungaryGoose thanks guy, let me go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute this directly from the pdf of $X$:
\begin{align}
P(X\geq \epsilon)&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\epsilon^\infty e^{-x^2/2} \, dx\\
&\geq\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon+1}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\
&\geq\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\epsilon+1)^2/2}\cdot 1\\
&\geq \frac13 e^{-(\epsilon+1)^2/2},
\end{align}
where in the second line we used the fact that $e^{-x^2/2} > 0$, in the third line that $e^{-x^2/2}$ is a decreasing function, and in the last line that $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} = 0.3989... \geq 1/3$.

Comment: That's what I am looking for! pretty answer, thanks!

Comment: are you looking for further explanation, or a different approach?

Comment: I'd like to find some other more tight lower boundaries of Normal Distributions, as there are some tight upper boundaries through the Markov's inequality or Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: sorry, I meant for this question, since I saw you accepted the answer and then took out the accept